# How can I set a limit size on all databases on a node in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger, database

I have the following scenario:

- Linux machine
- MongoDB 3.4.4 installed using WiredTiger storage engine

How can I set a limit on this machine, such that all the database sizes must not exceed together 500GB and any database must not exceed 150GB?
I would prefer if this setting can be done in `mongod.conf` file.

Comment: Define "database size". Mongodb has a bunch of size metrics: file size, data size, index size, etc.

Comment: Also, I haven't heard about size limitation capabilities. Likely, all you can do is monitor database sizes via `db.stats()` (or something) and trigger an alert in nagios or whatever monitoring tool you use, so that a human can act on it.

Comment: Cap your collection when you create the collection. But make sure it is big enough for your needs. See  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/

Comment: I want to limit the file size of the database (all collections). Capping collection doesn't work for me, since I'm not interested in collection size, but in total database size.